# Why is the border wider in Outlook client than in the web?

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

I am creating HTML template for Outlook and I want my 2 column table to have bottom borders on the columns like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qgEf.png), which I did by setting `border-bottom` property to the `td` element

Anyway, the picture is from the browser outlook, because when I open the client I see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEb60.png) .. as you can see the border of the last row is a single line, it's not split..to create a gap between the columns I use `border-right: 25px solid white` property.

Here is the situation with odd number of items [Img], (https://i.stack.imgur.com/231Af.png) I captured only the last 2 rows, but you can see the last item has a longer border than the upper ones. These tables are generated by code so all rows have the same properties, but still the last row makes the trouble.

The code is really long and messy, therefore I would like to ask without adding any code to the question. Do you have any ideas why this happens?

I have tried using a lot of CSS properties but none of them works.

Comment: CSS on email clients are limited and can be display differently on each provider. Search each feature [here](https://www.caniemail.com/).

Comment: Yeah sure, I would understand if this happened with each row, but to me it's weird that it happens only with the last row and have no idea why, because I set width to 50%

Comment: where's your code mate?